# I am developing an integration application which will integrate a SOAP API using WSDL. Can anyone guide me about relevant design patterns etc?

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, salesforce, apex-code

com Developer and working on an integration app that links an external system with Salesforce.com. The external system exposes its service through SOAP API and provides a WSDL which I have imported and classes are created under a namespace. I need help in developing the overall architecture of the application.

What should be the architecture of the system? Should I develop model and service classes for different entities for fetching data from external app and converting response into my own model classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat the external system as you would a typical data layer (DBMS, Web services, etc).  This means encapsulating the data fetching logic in such a way that the business layer has no idea where the data is coming from.  The [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) is one technique for doing this.

Once you have abstracted your data layer away, you would handle the translation of *Data* to *Entities* in whatever way you see fit.  You could use a tool such as [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to do this or write your own custom translation layer where the *Data* is translated into objects that your application works with.